# Administrating the logging directory

Tags: ros, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can you administrate usage of the ros logging dir (~/.ros/log)?

At the moment I suspect its only possible via the warning that roscore gives you on startup and use of [rosclean](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosclean). Is there an automated means of management?

**Solution**

Cannot set a maximum on the logging space, but as GeniusGeeko mentions below, you can wipe old logs fairly effectively using simple *nix magic. Put the following line in your user .bashrc:

```
find ~/.ros/log/* -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This will clean out any logs older than 5 days old. Alternatively you can put it in your system startup script (on ubuntu /etc/rc.local), just remember to convert the "~" to an explicit folder name pointing to your logs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9469/administrating-the-logging-directory/) by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3170 on 2011-03-17

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-03-18**:
How often would you like to "rosclean" your logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to do this..

> echo "find ~/.ros/log/* -mtime +5 -exec rm -r {} \;" >> ~/.bashrc

Replace the 5 with how many days you want to remove that was created before that number. This will remove files older than 5 days old.

It will search for old files every time you open a terminal.

---

Originally posted by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) with karma: 299 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-03-18**:
Good idea using find. I probably would not add it to my ~/.bashrc, but that would make a nice alias.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can modify the logging configuration of both roscpp and rospy via their logging configuration files in $ROS_ROOT/config .  That should enable you to disable or otherwise reduce the logging.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1